# Treat Enumeration<T> as Iterator<T>

Tags: java, iterator, foreach, enumeration, adapter

I have a class that implements the `Enumeration<T>` interface, but Java's foreach loop requires the `Iterator<T>` interface. Is there an `Enumeration` to `Iterator` Adapter in Java's standard library?

Comment: Its a lot simpler to either, not use Enumerator as its a legacy class or not use the "enhanced" for each loop.

Comment: The for-each loop requires an Iterable, not an Iterator; which do you really want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a so called "Adapter", to adapt the `Enumeration` to the otherwise incompatible `Iterator`. Apache commons-collections has [`EnumerationIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/EnumerationIterator.html). The usage is:

```
Iterator iterator = new EnumerationIterator(enumeration);
```

Comment: this is answering the question, because you can't use an iterator in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 34):

If you just want something to iterate over in a for-each loop (so an Iterable and not only an Iterator), [there's always](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list%28java.util.Enumeration%29) `java.util.Collections.list(Enumeration<T> e)` (without using any external libraries).

Comment: This is a simple answer, using a standard java class/method specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

a) I'm pretty sure you mean [`Enumeration`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), not `Enumerator`
b) [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) provides a Helper method [`Iterators.forEnumeration(enumeration)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#forEnumeration%28java.util.Enumeration%29) that generates an iterator from an Enumeration, but that won't help you either, as you need an `Iterable` (a provider of Iterators), not an `Iterator`
c) you *could* do it with this helper class:

```
public class WrappingIterable<E> implements Iterable<E>{
    private Iterator<E> iterator;

    public WrappingIterable(Iterator<E> iterator){
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator(){
        return iterator;
    }
}
```

And now your client code would look like this:

```
for(String string : new WrappingIterable<String>(
                        Iterators.forEnumeration(myEnumeration))){
    // your code here            
}
```

But is that worth the effort?

Comment: You could let your wrapper constructor accept an enumeration.

Comment: Also note that `Iterable` means you can ask for the iterator repeatedly.  This wrapper does not comply with that.

Answer (score 3):

No need to roll your own. Look at Google's Guava library. Specifically

```
Iterators.forEnumeration()
```

Comment: That makes an Iterator, not an Iterable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - The OP explicitly asked for an adapter from Enumeration to Iterator. He did not ask for Enumeration to Iterable.

Comment: He wants to use it in `foreach`, hence the `Iterator` is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that is part of the standard library.  Unfortunately you'll have to roll your own adapter.  There are examples out there of what others have done, for example:

[IterableEnumerator](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html)

Comment: Yes, there is something in the standard library specifically for this purpose: Collections.list

Answer (score 1):

or in commons-collections
EnumerationUtils

`import static org.apache.commons.collections.EnumerationUtils.toList`

```
toList(myEnumeration)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the class then you can simply implement `Iterator<T>` too and add the `remove` method..