# Iterate an Enumeration in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, iteration, enumeration, java-8

Is it possible to iterate an `Enumeration` by using Lambda Expression? What will be the Lambda representation of the following code snippet:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (nets.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = nets.nextElement();

}
```

I didn't find any stream within it.

Comment: Enumerations were replaced by Iterators in Java 1.2 in 1998.  It is unfortunate you still have to use it. :|

Comment: You can adapt your Enumeration to Iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007082/treat-enumerationt-as-iteratort

Comment: @PeterLawrey
Iterator came along, but there are still core APIs which use Enumeration.
Generics came along, but there are still core APIs which use bare types or return Object.
Lambdas came along, but Swing is still full of multi-method interfaces, so we can't use them.
It doesn't really surprise me anymore when I find APIs which Java forgot to modernise; it just saddens me.

Comment: @Trejkaz Yes, Swing still uses Vector and Hashtable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the Servlet API still uses Enumerations.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In case you don’t like the fact that `Collections.list(Enumeration)` copies the entire contents into a (temporary) list before the iteration starts, you can help yourself out with a simple utility method:

```
public static <T> void forEachRemaining(Enumeration<T> e, Consumer<? super T> c) {
  while(e.hasMoreElements()) c.accept(e.nextElement());
}
```

Then you can simply do `forEachRemaining(enumeration, lambda-expression);` (mind the `import static` feature)…

Answer (score 99):

<sub>(This answer shows one of many options. Just because is <strike>has</strike> had acceptance mark, doesn't mean it is the best one. I suggest reading other answers and picking one depending on situation you are in. IMO:</sub>

- for Java 8 [Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270470/1393766) is nicest, because aside from being simple it doesn't require additional iteration which happens in my solution.
- for Java 9 I would pick solution describe in [Tagir Valeev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627991/1393766))

---

You can copy elements from your [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) to [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with [`Collections.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list-java.util.Enumeration-) and then use it like

```
Collections.list(yourEnumeration).forEach(yourAction);
```

Comment: The catch is that now you have to store all the elements in a list. Which if it's small, is probably fine. But it's worth mentioning, because sometimes it will be too big to fit in memory.

Comment: How about java.util.stream.Stream#of(yourEnumeration.values()).forEach()?

Comment: @Filip Your comment is about [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) but question is about [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html).

Answer (score 53):

Since Java-9 there will be new default method [`Enumeration.asIterator()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/4be07e0eb9b6/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Enumeration.java#l84) which will make pure Java solution simpler:

```
nets.asIterator().forEachRemaining(iface -> { ... });
```

Answer (score 52):

If there are a lot of *Enumerations* in your code, I recommend creating a static helper method, that converts an *Enumeration* into a *Stream*. The static method might look as follows:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            new Iterator<T>() {
                public T next() {
                    return e.nextElement();
                }
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return e.hasMoreElements();
                }
            },
            Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}
```

Use the method with a *static import*. In contrast to Holger's solution, you can benefit from the different *stream* operations, which might make the existing code even simpler. Here is an example:

```
Map<...> map = enumerationAsStream(enumeration)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(groupingBy(...));
```

Comment: I think both are complementing each other just like `list.forEach(…)` and `list.stream(). ⟨stream ops⟩ .forEach(…)`.

Comment: How is this not part of the JDK?

Comment: `public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
   return Collections.list(e).stream();
}` would do the same, but much simpler.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch's proposal makes an intermediate copy of the list, which is what's being avoided.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following combination of standard functions:

```
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(CollectionUtils.toIterator(enumeration), Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), parallel)
```

You may also add more characteristics like `NONNULL` or `DISTINCT`.

After applying static imports this will become more readable:

```
stream(spliteratorUnknownSize(toIterator(enumeration), IMMUTABLE), false)
```

now you have a standard Java 8 Stream to be used in any way! You may pass `true` for parallel processing.

To convert from Enumeration to Iterator use any of:

- `CollectionUtils.toIterator()` from Spring 3.2 or you can use
- `IteratorUtils.asIterator()` from Apache Commons Collections 3.2
- `Iterators.forEnumeration()` from Google Guava

Comment: Where does CollectionUtils come from? Doesn’t seem to be in the JDK.

Comment: @Martin, it seems to be `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`.

Comment: @Vadzim I checked [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) 1.0, 2.0, 2.1.1, 3.2.1 and 4.0, but no class named CollectionUtils contains a method named toIterator.

Comment: Sorry, was confused, got it from Spring 3.2

Answer (score 8):

For Java 8 the simplest transformation of enumeration to stream is:

`Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()).stream()`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to present an alternative to Collections.asList and Stream functionality.  Since the question is titled "Iterate an Enumeration", I recognize sometimes you want to use a lambda expression but an enhanced for loop may be preferable as the enumerated object may throw an exception and the for loop is easier to encapsulate in a larger try-catch code segment (lambdas require declared exceptions to be caught within the lambda).  To that end, here is using a lambda to create an Iterable which is usable in a for loop and does not preload the enumeration:

```
 /**
 * Creates lazy Iterable for Enumeration
 *
 * @param <T> Class being iterated
 * @param e Enumeration as base for Iterator
 * @return Iterable wrapping Enumeration
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> enumerationIterable(Enumeration<T> e)
{
    return () -> new Iterator<T>()
    {
        @Override
        public T next()
        {
            return e.nextElement();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return e.hasMoreElements();
        }
    };
}
```