# How do I turn a Java Enumeration into a Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a third party library that gives me an `Enumeration<String>`.  I want to work with that enumeration lazily as a Java 8 `Stream`, calling things like `filter`, `map` and `flatMap` on it.

Is there an existing library that has this in it?  I am already referencing Guava and Apache Commons so if either of those have the solution that would be ideal.

Alternatively, what is the best/easiest way to turn an `Enumeration` into a `Stream` while retaining the lazy nature of everything?

Comment: related: [Iterate an Enumeration in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23261803/217324)

Comment: The question linked is asking how to turn an `Enumeration` (Java 1.0) into an `Iterator` (Java 1.2).  I'm asking how to turn it into a `Stream` (Java 1.8).  While it does appear that the the last answer in the linked question answers this, that answer is *wrong* for the question being asked.  That answer should be provided here so that future searchers can successfully find it.  Perhaps @ArneBurmeister would like to copy the answer here so this question is answered directly?

Comment: Reopened as the answers of the linked question do not discuss the lazy behavior and it also wouldn’t be the right place to post alternative ways to create a `Stream` (as that’s not the scope of the linked question).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23276455/2711488) already provides a solution which creates a `Stream` out of an `Enumeration`:

> ```
>  public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
>      return StreamSupport.stream(
>          Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
>              new Iterator<T>() {
>                  public T next() {
>                      return e.nextElement();
>                  }
>                  public boolean hasNext() {
>                      return e.hasMoreElements();
>                  }
>              },
>              Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
>  }
> ```

It should be emphasized that the resulting `Stream` *is* as lazy as any other `Stream`, as it won’t process any items before the terminal action has been commenced and if the terminal operation is short-circuiting, it will iterate only as many items as necessary.

Still, it has room for improvement. I’d always add a `forEachRemaining` method when there is a straight-forward way to process all elements. Said method will be called by the `Stream` implementation for most non-short-circuiting operations:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            new Iterator<T>() {
                public T next() {
                    return e.nextElement();
                }
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return e.hasMoreElements();
                }
                public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                    while(e.hasMoreElements()) action.accept(e.nextElement());
                }
            },
            Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}
```

However, the code above is a victim of the “using `Iterator` because it’s so familiar” antipattern. The created `Iterator` will get wrapped into an implementation of the new `Spliterator` interface and provides no advantage over implementing `Spliterator` directly:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if(e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    action.accept(e.nextElement());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                while(e.hasMoreElements()) action.accept(e.nextElement());
            }
    }, false);
}
```

On the source code level, this implementation is as simple as the `Iterator`-based, but eliminates the delegation from a `Spliterator` to an `Iterator`. It only requires its readers to learn about the new API.

Comment: Good stuff Holger. What are the advantages of using Spliterator.ORDERED here vs other values?

Comment: @IcedDante `ORDERED` means that there is a defined encounter order, so it implies that the Stream implementation is *not* allowed to do optimizations based on assuming the data to be unordered. Since for an unknown `Enumeration`, we don’t know whether the order has a meaning, we must assume that it *could* have a meaning and specify this characteristic. The caller still may call `unordered()` on the stream when they know that the order is irrelevant for the particular data, to enable optimizations. But our initial premise must be that the order could be important.

Comment: Note that there is `Enumeration#asIterator()` since java 9.

Answer (score 191):

Why not using vanilla Java :

```
Collections.list(enumeration).stream()...
```

However as mentionned by @MicahZoltu, the number of items in the enumeration has to be taken into account, as `Collections.list` will first iterate over the enumeration to copy the elements in an `ArrayList`. From there the regular `stream` method can be used. While this is usual for many collection stream operations, if the enumeration is too big (like infinite), this can cause problem because the enumeration has to be transformed in a `List` first (with a huge backing array), which may have impacts on the memory.

In this case the other approaches described in other answers should be used instead.

E.g. use the great `StreamEx` library, has it will iterate on the enumeration as needed see [Tagir Valeev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006958/48136).

Comment: That will enumerate the entire `enumeration`, to make it a list and then give you stream access to the list.  If the enumeration is small, this probably is a reasonable approach.  If the enumeration is very large this could be an expensive and unnecessary operation.  If the enumeration is infinite, this will crash your application.

Comment: @MicahZoltu Indeed. That is a point to consider, I'll update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 54):

In Java 9 it is possible to convert an `Enumeration` to a `Stream` with a one-liner:

```
Enumeration<String> en = ... ;
Stream<String> str = StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(en.asIterator(), Spliterator.ORDERED),
    false
);
```

(Well, it's a rather long line.)

If you're not on Java 9, you can convert the `Enumeration` into an `Iterator` manually using the technique given in [Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33243700/1441122).

Comment: We can make almost everything a one-liner if we make the line long enough ;^)

Answer (score 13):

According to [Guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#forEnumeration(java.util.Enumeration)), you could use the `Iterators.forEnumeration()` method:

```
Enumeration<Something> enumeration = ...;

Iterator<SomeThing> iterator = Iterators.forEnumeration(enumeration);
```

And in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/java8-iterator-to-stream), it is explained how to get a stream from an iterator:

```
Stream<Something> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
    false);
```

Comment: Although it may work in this case, that iterable is not really an Iterable: you can iterate it exactly once!

Comment: @dfogni The same happens with streams. Use and discard, they say :)

Comment: In context it is perfectly ok, but it is a bug waiting to happen because it declares an object with different semantics than what its interface say. More importantly it is IMHO an abuse of the Iterable interface, which by chance happens to be assignable from a lambda, but is not supposed to be an @FunctionalInterface

Answer (score 8):

In my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library there's simple method [`StreamEx.of(Enumeration)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#of-java.util.Enumeration-) which does the job:

```
Stream<String> stream = StreamEx.of(enumeration);
```

Note that it not just a shortcut to the @Holger solution, but implemented in different manner. In particular, it has significantly better parallel execution characteristics compared to solutions involving `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize()`.