# Transforming a while loop to a stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

As an exercise I'm converting some old code to functional streams.  I don't know much about streams. It seems like it should be simple to convert this code, but I haven't had much luck.  The method starts at a given integer, passes it to isPrime, which returns true if it's prime. and then hands off the new(next) prime number to be printed. If isPrime is false i is incremented and we check the next integer.

```
private static int nextPrime(final int number) {
    int i = number + 1;

    while (!isPrime(i)) {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert such a simple loop? And what problem did you encounter when you “haven't had much luck”? And what is your method supposed to do when there is no next prime in the `int` value range? The current behavior of overflowing doesn’t look much convincing.

Comment: @Holger "As an exercise..."

Answer (score 7):

I see no reason to use a `Stream` for this other than to take advantage of parallelism (if the primes happen to be very far apart, but this won't be true within `int` bounds, so there's essentially no benefit).

You can iterate over an `IntStream` of ascending integers (starting from `number + 1`) and filter only the prime numbers.  When one is inevitably found, you can return the first.

```
private static int nextPrime(final int number) {
    return IntStream.iterate(number + 1, i -> i + 1)
                    .filter(Test::isPrime)
                    .findFirst()
                    .getAsInt();
}
```

**Note**: The class that I used to test this is called `Test`, as seen by the method reference.  You should change that to your class name.

Comment: An infinite stream can never return an empty optional.

Comment: True, I'll convey that better.

Comment: @Aominè Good catch, I forgot it's not `get` for `OptionalInt` ;)

Comment: I realize there's no NEED for a stream.  I'm just trying to learn functional programming be transforming code I know already works.  The code you gave was a big help.  I'm SLOWLY getting my head around it.

Comment: I’d prefer `IntStream.rangeClosed(number+1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`; it’s more efficient and the behavior of throwing a `NoSuchElementException` when there is no bigger prime, is more reasonable than overflowing…

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33243700/636849), for an object like an `Enumeration<T>` for example, where you can only call `.hasMoreElements()` & `.nextElement()`, you can use this kind of code :

```
public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if(e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    action.accept(e.nextElement());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                while(e.hasMoreElements()) action.accept(e.nextElement());
            }
    }, false);
}
```