# How to get all Session values and names?

Tags: java, jsp, session

if i have values in a session and i need to get all the values in a session like

```
String[] name = request.getParameterValues("values");
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

for(String temp:name)
{
    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("a", temp);
        out.println("a is Running<br>");
    }

    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("b", temp);
        out.println("b is Running<br>");
    }

    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("c", temp);
        out.println("c is Running<br>");
    }

    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("d", temp);
        out.println("d is Running<br>");
    }

    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("e", temp);
        out.println("e is Running<br>");
    }

    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("f", temp);
        out.println("f is Running<br>");
    }
}
```

- if I get a set of checkbox values to a string. Im setting all the
  values which are selected in a .jsp to a session object. I need to
  retrieve only the selected values in a jsp which are saved in the
  above code.

Answer (score 20):

```
Enumeration<String> attributes = request.getSession().getAttributeNames();
while (attributes.hasMoreElements()) {
    String attribute = (String) attributes.nextElement();
    System.out.println(attribute+" : "+request.getSession().getAttribute(attribute));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        Enumeration e = (Enumeration) (session.getAttributeNames());

        while ( e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            Object tring;
            if((tring = e.nextElement())!=null)
            {
                out.println(session.getValue((String) tring));
                out.println("<br/>");
            }

        }
```

this code is also working perfectly 
thanks for the spark reply @karim mohsen

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumeration keys = session.getAttributeNames();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()){
   String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
   out.println(key + ": " + session.getValue(key) + "<br>");
}
```

this code is working on jsp

Comment: getValue and putValue are deprecated. New method names are getAttribute and setAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumeration attributeNames = session.getAttributeNames();
while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String temp= attributeNames.nextElement();
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("a", temp);
                out.println("a is Running<br>");
            }
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("b", temp);
                out.println("b is Running<br>");
            }
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("c", temp);
                out.println("c is Running<br>");
            }
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("d", temp);
                out.println("d is Running<br>");
            }
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("e", temp);
                out.println("e is Running<br>");
            }
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("f", temp);
                out.println("f is Running<br>");
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is done in JSP

emun= session.getAttributeNames(); // getting all attributes names in session %>

Answer (score 0):

### One-liner:

By converting Enumeration to a list or stream (Improved upon Max CodeSmith's answer)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames()).forEach(name -> System.out.println(name + " : " + session.getAttribute(name)));
```

More info:

1. [Iterate an Enumeration in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261803/iterate-an-enumeration-in-java-8)
2. [How do I turn a Java Enumeration into a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242577/how-do-i-turn-a-java-enumeration-into-a-stream)