# Java9 'asIterator' equivalent implementation in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

Below piece of code is using `asIterator()` method from Java 9 can someone please help me to convert below code compatible with Java 8?

```
private static Function<ClassLoader, Stream<URL>> asURLs(String packageDir) {
    return cl -> {
      try {
        Iterator<URL> iterator = cl.getResources(packageDir).asIterator();
        return StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UnhandledIOException(e);
      }
    };
```

Comment: You could "steal" it from a newer JDK, it's a couple lines of code: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ad348a8cec50561d3e295b6289772530f541c6b1/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Enumeration.java#L119 - I think that may have happened in this answer once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23276455/7916438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, look up "jdk source code" in your favourite search engine to find the source of `asIterator`, so that you can copy it. You'll find it here:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Enumeration.java

There you'll find `Enumeration.asIterator()`, which is an interface default method. You can define it locally as a method that takes an Enumeration argument:

```
private static <E> Iterator<E> asIterator(Enumeration<E> enumeration) {
    return new Iterator<>() {
        @Override public boolean hasNext() {
            return enumeration.hasMoreElements();
        }
        @Override public E next() {
            return enumeration.nextElement();
        }
    };
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
    Iterator<URL> iterator = asIterator(cl.getResources(packageDir));
```

However, @tevemadar commented with a link to an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261803/iterate-an-enumeration-in-java-8/23276455#23276455) that might suit you better

Comment: interface default method is feature of java 8 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/

Comment: Thank you @k314159 but one more silly question. I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'E'` how to get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks, @user16320675, I've modified my answer with your correction.