# Does adapter pattern is used in my class diagram?

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

I did my homework that makes some program which has to use adapter pattern.

But I'm not sure about I used adaptor pattern in homework.

Can you check my diagram and adaptor pattern used?

[image]

I designed Car, Plane, Submarine as a adaptor classes which connect Vehicle super class and PrintStates interface.

Am I right?

---

> There are 5 menu options (P)lane, (C)ar, (S)ubmarine,
>   (B)lackbox, (H)alt and if user input button P/C/S, then all states of
>   that object has shown, button B is the history of user's select and
>   states of objects. Lastly, button H is to exit program.

Below is the execution of program.

[image]

Comment: Seems only a simple inheritance and polymorphism is what you have used and it suffices in this case

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow. It belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

You use the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to convert the interface of a class into another interface the client expects.

Usually, the application of the adapter pattern involves a target interface, an implementation of the target interface and an adaptee interface. The application of Adapter I like the most is to [convert Enumeration as an Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007082/treat-enumerationt-as-iteratort).

In your work, classes `Car`, `Plane` and `Submarine` extends `Vehicle` and they all implement `PrintStates`. `Plane` and `Submarine` override some of the methods in the `Vehicle`. Without knowing your requirement, it is difficult to understand why that is. But, I cannot see the application of the Adapter pattern here.

---

It would be useful if you can edit your post stating how you *intended* to implement the Adapter pattern here so that we can help you get your design right.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I updated. could you check?